# Using the LookbackAPI to find Scope Change

Tags: rally

Is there a way to query using the LookbackAPI to find all the stories (HierarchicalRequirement) that had a change to PlanEstimate from a certain date (say a week ago) to today?

Or is the best way to do that to find all stories on a given date in the past and return the PlanEstimate and UnformatedID fields, and then compare them to the current PlanEstimate for each story as of today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each LBAPI Snapshot will have a `_PreviousValues` collection. For each LBAPI Snapshot, if a field has changed from the prior snapshot, then the `_PreviousValues` collection will be hydrated for that value. In other words, if the `PlanEstimate` has not changed between snapshots, then there will be no `PlanEstimate` entry in the `_PreviousValues` collection for that snapshot. Thus, for PlanEstimate, the following query:

```
find: {
    "_TypeHierarchy" : "HierarchicalRequirement",
    "_PreviousValues.PlanEstimate" : {$exists: true},
    "_ValidFrom": {
        $gte: "2013-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        $lt: "2013-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Should provide you with any HierarchicalRequirement snapshots corresponding to a change in PlanEstimate from 2013-05-01 to 2013-05-10.